# Windows (or WSL) keeps blocking ports after running a server

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-defender

I'm running some nodejs, python and golang servers within WSL in Windows 10 (1809). For the past few weeks, I'm faced with a particularly irritating behaviour, where any port I use to run a web-server gets blocked on subsequent restarts. Even after a cold reboot, I can't get my servers to run on the same port. Running `netstat -a -q -n` doesn't show those ports in the list either. I've checked my Windows Defender Firewall, and there are no specific rules which would block ports either.

To illustrate:

1. I run an npm package `storybook` - it starts a web-server on port 9001.
2. After running the server and working on it for sometime, I close it.
3. Restart my computer.
4. I try running the server again, and I get this error:

```
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:14001
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1378:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1466:7)
    at listenToServer (/mnt/d/Workspace/ui/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/build-dev.js:172:20)
    at buildDevStandalone (/mnt/d/Workspace/ui/node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/build-dev.js:293:29)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

If I run `python -m http.server 9001`, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\server.py", line 1211, in <module>
    test(HandlerClass=handler_class, port=args.port, bind=args.bind)
  File "C:\Users\default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\server.py", line 1185, in test
    with ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass) as httpd:
  File "C:\Users\default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Is there anyway out of this ******* mess?

Comment: Some experiments: 1. Try to move the node module to home folder aka. `/home/your-name`. 2. Remove Windows paths froim WSL ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336147)). 3. Allow that port in Windows Firewall for all programs (or disable firewall temporarily for testing).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, I've found that it's not an issue with node at all. Even python doesn't run (`python -m http.server 14001`) doesn't work. Also, I've also tested point #3 and can't find any change. I've tried enabling firewall logging too (for all 3 networks - public, private, domain), but didn't even see the port being hit (although here I'm just desperate as I don't actually know if Windows Firewall does indeed log a port being hit from localhost)

Comment: I don't see how point #2 will help - I'll try it out nonetheless...